# How to solve the problem Expected argument of type "?string", "array" given at property path "ui_ux"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, easyadmin

Hello to the community,

I would like your help with two problems I am having with sending documents via my form and how I can display them in easyadmin please.
I've been stuck for some time on these two problems and all the answers I've found on the net haven't managed to get me out of this situation :'(

My documentsTypephp

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Documents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Data;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class DocumentsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(
        FormBuilderInterface $builder,
        array $options
    ): void {
        $builder

            ->add('description', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Description',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Description',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('ui_ux', FileType::class, [
                'multiple' => false,
                'data_class' => null,
                'label' => ' Si UX/ UI',
                'mapped' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => '',
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '1024k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'application/pdf',
                            'application/x-pdf',
                            'application/doc',
                            'application/docx',
                            'application/figx',
                            'application/odt',
                            'application/ott',
                            'application/jpg',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' =>
                            'Please upload a valid PDF, document, Figma file',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
```

this is my documentsphp

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\DocumentsRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DocumentsRepository::class)]
class Documents
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTime $sending_date = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'documents')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    private ?User $users = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 400, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $ui_ux = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 400, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $seo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 400, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $image_service = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Services::class, inversedBy: 'documents')]
    private Collection $services;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSendingDate(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->sending_date;
    }

    public function setSendingDate(\DateTime $sending_date): self
    {
        $this->sending_date = $sending_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsers(): ?User
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function setUsers(?User $users): self
    {
        $this->users = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUiUx(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ui_ux;
    }

    public function setUiUx(?string $ui_ux): self
    {
        $this->ui_ux = $ui_ux;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSeo(): ?string
    {
        
        return $this->seo;
    }

    public function setSeo(?string $seo): self
    {
        $this->seo = $seo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImageService(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image_service;
    }

    public function setImageService(?string $image_service): self
    {
        $this->image_service = $image_service;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Services>
     */
    public function getServices(): Collection
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function addService(Services $service): self
    {
        if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services->add($service);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeService(Services $service): self
    {
        $this->services->removeElement($service);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and my second probleme realted to this one is how can i watch the documents in my easyadmin ?
I have this when i can send just one document

[image]

thank you very much indeed for your time to you all.

Comment: But what unclear is in error message you are having?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski the message i have is Expected argument of type "?string", "array" given at property path 'ux_ui' when i type multiple = true to send more than one document

Comment: That's irrelevant. whatever you send does not affect type signature. Also by logic, the **entity** is an entity. If you are sending more data, then apparently you need to create more entities from it.